# Unable to write results in a csv file in some customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script to parse the `singers`, `their concerning links`, `actors` and `their concerning links` out of different containers from a webpage. The script is doing fine. What I can't do is write the results in a csv file accordingly.

[Webpage link](https://www.hindigeetmala.net/movie/2_states.htm)

I've tried with:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://www.hindigeetmala.net'
link = 'https://www.hindigeetmala.net/movie/2_states.htm'

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

with open("hindigeetmala.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['singer_records','actor_records'])

    for item in soup.select("tr[itemprop='track']"):
        try:
            singers = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in item.select("span[itemprop='byArtist']") if i.get_text(strip=True)]
        except Exception: singers = ""

        try:
            singer_links = [urljoin(base_url,i.get("href")) for i in item.select("a:has(> span[itemprop='byArtist'])") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception: singer_links = ""
        singer_records = [i for i in zip(singers,singer_links)]

        try:
            actors = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in item.select("a[href^='/actor/']") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception: actors = ""
        try:
            actor_links = [urljoin(base_url,i.get("href")) for i in item.select("a[href^='/actor/']") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception: actor_links = ""
        actor_records = [i for i in zip(actors,actor_links)]
        song_name = item.select_one("span[itemprop='name']").get_text(strip=True)
        writer.writerow([singer_records,actor_records,song_name])
        print(singer_records,actor_records,song_name)
```

If I execute the script as is, this is [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VZKV.jpg) I get.

When I try like `writer.writerow([*singer_records,*actor_records,song_name])`, I get this type of [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1QB.jpg). Only the first pair of tuple is written.

This is my expected [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZafN.jpg).

> How can I write the result, as in name and their links in a csv file according to the third image?

PS All the images of the output represent the first column of csv files for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with feedback from SIM, I think this is what you looking for (I just added one function for formatting your lists)

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base_url = 'https://www.hindigeetmala.net'
link = 'https://www.hindigeetmala.net/movie/2_states.htm'

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")


def merge_results(inpt):
    return [','.join(nested_items for nested_items in
                     [','.join("'" + tuple_item + "'" for tuple_item in item)
                      for item in inpt])]


with open("hindigeetmala.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['singer_records', 'actor_records'])

    for item in soup.select("tr[itemprop='track']"):
        try:
            singers = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in item.select(
                "span[itemprop='byArtist']") if i.get_text(strip=True)]
        except Exception:
            singers = ""

        try:
            singer_links = [urljoin(base_url, i.get("href")) for i in item.select(
                "a:has(> span[itemprop='byArtist'])") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception:
            singer_links = ""
        singer_records = [i for i in zip(singers, singer_links)]

        try:
            actors = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in item.select(
                "a[href^='/actor/']") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception:
            actors = ""
        try:
            actor_links = [urljoin(base_url, i.get("href")) for i in item.select(
                "a[href^='/actor/']") if i.get("href")]
        except Exception:
            actor_links = ""
        actor_records = [i for i in zip(actors, actor_links)]
        song_name = item.select_one(
            "span[itemprop='name']").get_text(strip=True)
        writer.writerow(merge_results(singer_records) +
                        merge_results(actor_records)+[song_name])
        print(singer_records, actor_records, song_name)
```

Comment: `song_name` doesn't seem to be a list.

Comment: I think OP is trying to write all the information of `singer_records`  in a single cell and so on but the way you suggested will spread across columns.